# Fail to Download File Using Jmeter and relative path

Tags: jmeter, relative-path

I'm using JMeter to test concurrent downloads, and need to store it into specific folder.

I'm working on windows and using "Save response to a file". If I use the absolute path it all works exactly as I want it to work.

Now, I need to share this with a group (will be stored in repo) and want to change my obviously wrong absolute path to relative.

Now:
"~" - stores download in project root folder, where .JMX file is, but I want it in: "~/downloads/" so, in subfolder.

None of "regular" things work and yes I tried all possible combinations even those I know it should not work at all. 
~/downloads/
./downloads/
~./downloads/
\downloads\
\downloads\
...

It or fails, and I can see in log error like:
~\downloads\1.x-gzip (The system cannot find the path specified)

Or It get's store in root with the filename "downloads" instead 1.x-gzip

Is there a way to do it, maybe using beanshell?

Most important, why is that behavior in JMeter so different, I mean if it works for "home" and "~/../" why it does not recognize subfolders?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JMeter seems to be removing trailing slash so there is no way to bypass it apart from providing full path to the folder.

If you need to do it dynamically, relevant Beanshell script will look like:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "downloads" + System.getProperty("file.separator"),)}
```

You need to have "downloads" folder at the same level with your .jmx test script.

References:

- [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) - function
- [FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) class JavaDoc
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)